# Unchecking items in IToolbar?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, toolbar

I currently have an app with two menu bars. One being the AxToolbarControl in a UserControl and one in a separate menu bar containing in-house stuff.

I currently have the issue where if I select something in the AxToolBarControl and then select something in the other menu-bar the item in the AxControl is still checked.  This obviously results in two commands being executed on the mousedown event handler.

I've looked at the IControl and IToolbar but it looks like .Checked is a ReadOnly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can always set the buddy control to null and back to mapControl but that's not clean

Comment: Can you set .CurrentTool to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the buddy control to null and back to mapControl.  Not elegant but it works.

Comment: That's my philosophy.